# LINQ to SQL использование списка как фильтр

Tags: c#, linq2sql

Помогите разобраться. Я только начал изучать Sharp и LINQ по этому каждый шаг дается с трудом, вот и сейчас столкнулся с проблемой, решение которой не могу найти уже несколько дней.

Есть 3 таблицы "Сотрудники", "Движение сотрудников" и "Должности", мне нужно объединить "Сотрудники" и "Должности" используя "Движение" в качестве посредника (взяв от туда последнюю запись по каждому сотруднику), соответственно в движении может быть как одна запись на сотрудника, так и десять.

В результате получился код который создает нужный мне список посредник, но в конечном результате выдает "Локальная последовательность не может быть использована в реализациях операторов запросов LINQ to SQL, кроме оператора Contains".

```
List<WorkerMove> Rank = new List<WorkerMove>();
var idRank = (from rank1 in context.Worker select rank1.codeWorker);

foreach (var read in idRank)
 {      
  WorkerMove Rank3 = (from rank2 in context.WorkerMove 
                      where rank2.idWorker == read 
                      select rank2).FirstOrDefault();

  if(Rank3 != null) Rank.Add(Rank3);
 }

 var workerSurname = from worker in context.Worker
     join workMove in Rank on worker.codeWorker equals workMove.idWorker 
     join workRank in context.Dol on workMove.idRank equals workRank.idDol 
     select new
     {
      codeWork = worker.codeWorker,
      Fio = worker.Family+ " " + worker.Name.Remove(1) + "." + worker.Otch.Remove(1) + ".",
      Dol = workRank.Dol,
     };
```

Понятно что проблема в моей попытке использовать Rank в качестве присоединенной таблицы. Сейчас думаю передать список элементов во временную таблицу на стороне сервера и использовать ее в качестве посредника. Но наверняка есть другие способы решения задачи.

p.s. структура таблиц:

Сотрудники (Worker) = {codeWorker (int), NameWorker (string)}

Движение (workerMove) = {idMove (int), idWorker (int), idRank (int), Data (DateTime)}

Должность (Dol) = {idDol (int), Dol(string)}

codeWorker (int)=idWorker (int)

idRank (int) = idDol (int)

Comment: Приведите в вопросе структуру ваших трёх классов. Все поля не надо, достаточно только ключевые свойства.

Comment: А К, классов нет, есть только таблицы на SQL сервере. Удалось решить задачу путем использования в качестве буфера временной таблицы на стороне сервера. Но время выполнения запроса достаточно большое, да и я просто уверен что есть способ проще : )

Comment: а зачем вообще делать foreach и firstordefault - если их убрать получится один большой запрос

Comment: @Grundy в этих двух вещах весть смысл запроса. Таблица Движение содержит передвижение по должности человека, например он был младшим сотрудником и тут его повысили до просто сотрудника, соответственно в Движении будет две записи и две должности у Иванова, а может быть и больше. В цикле foreach выбираются все записи про Иванова, а firstordefault добавляет последнюю (актуальную) в список Rank, таким образом список не дублирует сотрудников и  указывает их должности в зависимости от выбранной даты. Всего 64 должности и 1500 сотрудников, постоянно кто-то куда-то двигается, уходит или приходит.

Comment: @LeRos, как же последнюю, если первую? :-) где-то происходит сортировка?

Comment: @Grundy, здесь ее нет, это уже мелочи, нужно добавить сортировку по дате (от большего к меньшему), в запросе  Rank3, тогда будет браться первый элемент с наибольшей/более поздней датой. А так же добавить в условие отбора запроса все значения меньше даты заданной переменной. Тогда если делать выбор по переменной даты и она будет меньше последнего назначения, то и запрос выдаст предыдущую должность. Проблема то в другом, я не могу использовать переменную Rank в запросе workerSurname, видимо ее нужно привести к другому типу или еще что то сделать, а вот чего я не знаю : (

Comment: @LeRos, я ж сказал - тебе не нужны твои foreach и firstordefault - они заставляют тебя сохранять Rank в памяти, без них ты можешь все впихнуть в один запрос

Comment: @Grundy, и как тогда убрать дубликаты записей ? как построить условие запроса что бы он выбирал из списка по 1 экземпляру записи для каждого сотрудника, с актуальной должностью ?

Comment: @Grundy, кажется понял! нужно пересчет сделать после объединения : ) спасибо за помощь!

Comment: не понял что ты имеешь ввиду под пересчетом. Но если ты решил проблему - добавь свой ответ.

Comment: Имеется ввиду foreach запустить уже после запроса workerSurname и грузить результат в нужное место (в моем случае List WPF), а не в Rank, к сожалению проверить смогу только через два дня, смена кончилась : ((( если код будет рабочий то добавлю ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переработал код следующим образом:

```
List<int> Rank = new List<int>();
var workerSurname = from worker in context.Worker
join workMove in context.WorkerMove on worker.codeWorker equals workMove.idWorker 
join workRank in context.Dol on workMove.idRank equals workRank.idDol

select new //выбор всего списка сотрудников, включающий все передвижения
 {
  codeWork = worker.codeWorker, 
  Fio = worker.Name,
  Dol = workRank.Dol
 };

var Rankid = (from rank1 in context. Worker select rank1. codeWorker); //создание списка ID Сотрудников (без дубликатов)
foreach (var read in Rankid)
 {
  //сравнение списка ID сотрудников с обобщенным списком и выбор актуальной записи 
  var Rank3 = (from rank2 in workerSurname where rank2.codeWork == read select rank2).FirstOrDefault(); 
  Rank.Add(Rank3.codeWork); // добавление выбранной записи в лист
 }
```

Это кусок отредактированного кода, отражающий общий смысл, в оригинале пришлось добавить еще много чего, что бы ускорить работу, но основной вопрос "Как сформировать подобный список" решен.